# firewall not working as expected in kickstart

Tags: linux, centos, kickstart, tftp, tftpd

I have following line in kickstart for firewall

```
firewall --enabled --service=ssh,glusterfs,tftp,ntp
```

I am expecting tftp server should be accessible from other system, but it was only accessible from local server.

```
firewall-cmd  --list-services
ssh dhcpv6-client
```

i did following steps and it start working

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=tftp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Why kickstart firewall command not working neither throwing any error

**Update1:** After reply of @Gracefulrestart
I tried following options and still no success

```
firewall --enabled --service=ssh --service=glusterfs --service=tftp --service=ntp
firewall --enabled --service={ssh,glusterfs,tftp,ntp}
```

Output of list services is

```
firewall-cmd  --list-services
ssh dhcpv6-client
```

After adding manually

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=tftp

firewall-cmd  --list-services
ssh dhcpv6-client tftp
```

Following are logs excerpt from  `/var/log/anaconda/journal.log`

```
Apr 23 10:48:10 localhost program[6875]: Running... /usr/bin/firewall-offline-cmd --enabled --port=30083:tcp --port=9090:tcp --port=8080:tcp --service=tftp --service=ssh --service=glusterfs --service=ntp
Apr 23 10:48:10 localhost systemd[1]: Started Locale Service.
Apr 23 10:48:10 localhost program[6875]: INVALID_SERVICE: 'glusterfs' not among existing services
Apr 23 10:48:10 localhost program[6875]: Adding service 'tftp' to default zone.
Apr 23 10:48:10 localhost program[6875]: Adding service 'ssh' to default zone.
Apr 23 10:48:10 localhost program[6875]: ALREADY_ENABLED: ssh
Apr 23 10:48:10 localhost program[6875]: Adding service 'glusterfs' to default zone.
Apr 23 10:48:10 localhost program[6875]: Adding service 'ntp' to default zone.
Apr 23 10:48:10 localhost program[6875]: Adding port '30083/tcp' to default zone.
Apr 23 10:48:10 localhost program[6875]: Adding port '9090/tcp' to default zone.
Apr 23 10:48:10 localhost program[6875]: Adding port '8080/tcp' to default zone.
Apr 23 10:48:10 localhost program[6875]: Return code: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below details to fix this issue, As per official docs

```
A minimal installation's %packages section which will also configure the firewall 
will look similar to the following:

%packages
@Core
authconfig
system-config-firewall-base
```

in my case `authconfig` was missing.

Second also follow suggestion of @GracefulRestart for proper syntax

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to pass the service option once for each service you are adding to the firewall:

`firewall --enabled --service=ssh --service=glusterfs --service=tftp --service=ntp`

I cannot remember if you can use bash brace expansion in kickstart, but it would look close to what you originally had:

`firewall --enabled --service={ssh,glusterfs,tftp,ntp}`

Comment: Sorry for late update, i have updated question under update1: for sake of better formatting